# CoordinatorLayout.Behavior not being called

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement coordinator layout behavior on a custom FAB menu as described [here](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/)

The program compiles and runs but the coordinator layout behavior functions are never called so the SnackBar overlays the FAB menu.

The only other question on SO about it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735603/coordinator-layout-custom-layout-behavior-never-getting-called) but the solution provided is not my issue.

Here is the xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_host"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="com.companionfree.quizinator.couple.shared.FloatingActionMenuBehavior"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorAccent">


        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_host_bluetooth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_white_24dp"/>


        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_host_nearby"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_4_bar_white_24dp"/>


    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my CoordinatorLayout.Behavior class:

```
public class FloatingActionMenuBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionsMenu> {

  public FloatingActionMenuBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {}

  @Override
  public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionsMenu child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionsMenu child, View dependency) {
      float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
    child.setTranslationY(translationY);
    return true;
  }
}
```

There are no errors, the snackbar displays, it just overlays the FAB menu...I can't seem to figure out where the error is.

Comment: This has the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802886/move-cardview-on-snackbar-co-ordinator-layout

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar I reviewed the answers in that question and found nothing useful. Perhaps you could explain what I missed?

Comment: Alright. Can you post the code when you display the snackbar. I want to see how you make the snackbar and display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the snack bar to push the FAB you need to pass the FloatingActionsMenu view to the snackBar while making it.

```
 Snackbar.make(FloatingActionsMenuVIEWINSTANCEHERE, mErrorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

and then call the show() method. This should fix the issue

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I had it being called in a Fragment using getView().  I found it separately here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-the-Snackbar but I'll give you the win :)